# Deployar api con FastApi y nginx

Tags: python, api, nginx

Tengo una api con fastApi corriendo en localhost de mi servidor y necesito deployarla para conectarme desde fuera a través de nginx.

Ejecuto el comando:

`uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000`

Y en mi archivo de configuracion de nginx tengo:

```
location /opc {

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    }
```

Este es un ejemplo de una funcion del controlador:

`@app.get("opc/get-status/{machine}")`

Y el servidor siempre me devuelve el mismo error:

```
{
    "detail": "Not Found"
}
```

Entiendo que no encuentra la ruta, ya que me devuelve un 404, pero no entiendo porque.

Gracias,
Un saludo.

Comment: Pon el url al que haces `get`. Pero creo que necesitas agregar `/` `@app.get("/opc/get-status/{machine}")`

Comment: Si, también he probado con eso, pero tampoco funciona...

Comment: ¿Alguna otra idea o ayuda? Gracias!

Comment: Creo que nginx ya esta capturando `opc`. Intenta la ruta `/opc/opc/...`

Comment: Lo he probado @loki, pero sigue igual...

Comment: Ya no se. Si pudieras compartir un ejemplo mínimo en github.